# SQLiteOpenHelper getWritableDatabse() fails with no Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a very strange problem. It only shows from time to time, on several devices. Can't seem to reproduce it when I want, but had it so many times, that I think I know where I get it.

So I have a `Loader` which connects to sqlite through a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
try {
    Log.i(TAG, "Get details offline / db helper: "+DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getContext()));
    SQLiteDatabase db=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this.getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i(TAG, "Get details offline / db: "+db);
    //doing some work on the db...
} catch(SQLiteException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    //trying everything to grab some exception or whatever
}
```

My `SQLIteOpenHelper` looks something like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;
    private static Context mCxt;

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context cxt) {
        //using app context as suggested by CommonsWare
        Log.i("DBHELPER1", "cxt"+mCxt+" / instance: "+mInstance);
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(cxt.getApplicationContext());
        }
        Log.i("DBHELPER2", "cxt"+mCxt+" / instance: "+mInstance);
        mCxt = cxt;
        return mInstance;
    }

    //private constructor
    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mCxt = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //some tables created here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //upgrade code here
    }
}
```

It really works great in most cases. But from time to time I get a log similar to this:

```
06-10 23:49:59.621: I/DBHELPER1(26499): cxtcom.myapp@407152c8 / instance: com.myapp.helpers.DatabaseHelper@40827560
06-10 23:49:59.631: I/DBHELPER2(26499): cxtcom.myapp@407152c8 / instance: com.myapp.helpers.DatabaseHelper@40827560
06-10 23:49:59.631: I/DetailsLoader(26499): Get event details offline / db helper: com.myapp.helpers.DatabaseHelper@40827560
06-10 23:49:59.631: I/DBHELPER1(26499): cxtcom.myapp@407152c8 / instance: com.myapp.helpers.DatabaseHelper@40827560
06-10 23:49:59.651: I/DBHELPER2(26499): cxtcom.myapp@407152c8 / instance: com.myapp.helpers.DatabaseHelper@40827560
```

This line `Log.i(TAG, "Get details offline / db: "+db);` never gets called! No Exceptions, silence. Plus, the thread with the `Loader` is not running anymore.

So nothing past the line:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this.getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
```

gets executed.

What can possibly go wrong on this line?

Comment: uhm, `getWritableDatabase` throws error when you cannot open database for write, specify closer when it throw this error. For what interaction with user.

Comment: Well it never does, that's the weird thing. As you can see in my code I even tried to catch both `SQLiteException` (which should be thrown according to docs) and `Exception`. This part of the Log I posted - that's it - nothing else shows... The app is responsive, but the `Loader` thread becomes dead

Comment: It might be a memory leak... this sounds especially likely since you seem to have a difficult time replicating the problem consistently. Try making the `Context` non-`static` and remove the line `mCxt = cxt;` from the `getInstance` method... if it doesn't help at all, update your code and I can take another look.

Comment: Funny thing is I had it this way for quite some time and gc behaved ok. Never found any leak and I check every now and then. But I updated the code with normal cxt and will try to reproduce it today. If it does work - great :-)

Comment: It's really hard to tell. I solved it and a bunch of other problems, but I really don't know which solution worked for which problem;) I made the context non-static, removed all `sqlite.close()` from my code and also changed the logic behind my, apparently, rubbish concept for offline/online Loader. Btw, if you had a minute, you could take a look at this concept here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856308/loadermanager-get-data-offline-then-online.

Comment: I see you've worked around this, but I thought I'd add that when I run into stuff like this I catch `Throwable`, which is really everything that can be thrown.